# Standard sql bigquery query fails

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-compute-engine

Why does following standard sql BigQuery query fail:

```
query_job = db.query('INSERT IGNORE INTO feature_engineering.population VALUES 
( 688, 9, 28.0, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, ((24.502362413708344 
60.31927864851714) (24.502328274396916 60.321522364418435) (24.506852321471555 
60.32153922011104) (24.506886150472955 60.31929550268306) (24.502362413708344 
60.31927864851714)) )')
```

Error message is: "Exception: 400 Syntax error: Parenthesized expression cannot be parsed as an expression, struct constructor, or subquery at [1:112]"

Comment: I guess the SQL engine can not parse the parenthesized expressions in that query. Can you show us the schema of your table? Maybe we could write a working query then.

Comment: Starting with 24.502... are you sure that you want double parentheses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's your schema definition for the following value?

((24.502362413708344 
60.31927864851714) (24.502328274396916 60.321522364418435) (24.506852321471555 
60.32153922011104) (24.506886150472955 60.31929550268306) (24.502362413708344 
60.31927864851714))

(notice there are no delimiters in this object)

In order to insert a 2-dimensional array like value, you'll need your schema column to be defined as REPEATED. You could as well use a STRING field and json.dumps() this 2-dimensional tuple into it. Depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: The schema definition is STRING, and I succeeded in storing the value as a string already. Thanks.